# Azure Data Factory - connect to onprem accdb

Tags: ms-access, azure-virtual-machine, azure-data-factory, on-premises-instances

I need to retrieve data from Access onprem database by using adf. I have integration runtime installed on azure vm. Access database is on the other virtual machine. I know that on the azure virtual machine I should have a path to that Access database but how to do that?

Comment: did I read correct that you installed the integration runtime on the azure machine? It needs to be installed on an on-premises VM!

Comment: So the only way is to install it on the same machine as its for accdb? I use azure vm because I have to also retrieve data from SQL server and it works good.

Comment: not necessarily on the same VM but at least somewhere on-premises. It makes it easier to install at the same machine as the access db because otherwise you have to share the location to another machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that on the azure virtual machine I should have a path to that Access database but how to do that?

- To connect on-premises Access database with Data factory **you need to install SHIR on that particular Virtual Machine**. Only for port 443 outbound traffic. This may be open by default.
- The Integration Runtime Machine needs to have the Microsoft Access ODBC driver installed for the data storage.

> Microsoft Access 2016 version of ODBC driver doesn't work with this connector. Use Microsoft Access 2013 or 2010 version of ODBC driver instead.

- In linked service select that particular SHIR hosted on that particular Virtual Machine.
- Provide correct values to the linked service properties like `connectionString`, `authenticationType`.

**Reference**- [Copy data from and to Microsoft Access using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-microsoft-access) follow this official document.